# NuGet PowerShell Core Console in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac 17.3

Tags: macos, nuget-package, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac, nuget-package-manager-console

Can someone tell me if we can access the Package manager console in VS 2022 for MAC 17.3

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a NuGet Package Manager Console available for Visual Studio for Mac as a separate extension you can install.

From the main menu, select Extensions to open the Extensions Manager, then select 'NuGet Extensions' and click the Install button.

[image: Extensions manager dialog]

Restart Visual Studio for Mac after installing the extension.

To open the NuGet Package Manager Console, from the View menu select Other Windows - NuGet Package Manager Console.

[image: NuGet Package Manager Console window]

Source code is on GitHub - https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions

If you are seeing a purple window, or Visual Studio for Mac crashes, then try the 0.31.1 version which can be downloaded from the [GitHub page](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions/releases/tag/v0.31.1-vsm17.3). This can be installed from the Extensions Manager dialog using the 'Install from file' button.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell):

> The Package Manager Console is built into the Package Manager for Visual Studio on Windows. Visual Studio Code and **Visual Studio for Mac don't include the console**. Visual Studio for Mac has a UI for managing NuGet packages, and the equivalent console commands are available through the [NuGet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference)